# JFileChooser and NTFS JunctionPoints / Symlinks?

Tags: java, windows, swing, ntfs, jfilechooser

The JFileChooser in Swing (Java 1.6.0_u25) doesn't seem to know how to deal with NTFS Junction Points or Symbolic Links.

The file chooser has no special handling:

`int rv = mainfileChooser.showOpenDialog(parentFrame)`

When using this on a Windows 7 box, the special folders under My Documents (My Pictures, My Videos, My Music) can't be entered - the user clicks on them, but nothing happens and they can't be selected.  After some experimentation, the same thing happens with any SymLink or Junction Point (both pre-generated by the OS and manually created.)

.lnk Shortcuts to directories work fine.

Is there a way to fix this and let my users save images in "My Pictures"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By an amazing coincidence, Java 1.6u27 just shipped, and includes a fix for this very issue!

Release Notes:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/6u27bugfixes-444150.html

Bug Writeup:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7012783

The bug discussion revolves around DFS links, rather than Junction points, but I believe the issues are the same, and testing this locally all the wacky behavior has gone away and I can save to My Pictures (and friends) just fine.

Comment: It is still not fixed in Oracle JRE 8u241

Answer (score 3):

The problem with those special types is that they are not cross-platform, so that's the reason JFileChooser doesn't support them.

You may want to use the native [XFileDialog](http://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/). Didn't use it by myself, but it seems relevant for you.
Keep in mind that it is native and will not be portable to Linux / OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Special folders work for me at least in the system look and feel.

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
} catch (InstantiationException e1) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
}
```

Comment: This will show very similar dialog to the native one, but you will not be able to see/navigate to the special directories !!!

Comment: I can browse my videos, my pictures, my music, etc in my app (on Windows 7, Latest Java 6). So I don't know why you can't.